# Meteor Subscribe to all pages

Tags: meteor

When I do a search to mongodb in a page, the result shows in all pages of my site, that is, make a search on the page "search1", i get a result. When I go to page "search2", the result I got in "search1" s there. I want to clean all pages from past results. Here's the example:

[meteorpad - bequipamentos](http://meteorpad.com/pad/hGmosMJmvpun4y7Jj/bequipamentos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.meteor/packages:**

```
...
kadira:flow-router
kadira:blaze-layout
...
```

**searchName.html:**

```
<template name="searchName">
    <div class="Search">
        {{#with result}}
            <div>{{name}}</div>
        {{/with}}
    </div>
</template>
```

**searchName.js:**

```
Template.searchName.helpers({
    result: function () {
        return Names.findOne();
    }
});
```

**searchCode.html:**

```
<template name="searchCode">
    <div class="SearchCode">
        {{#with result}}
            <div>{{code}}</div>
        {{/with}}
    </div>
</template>
```

**searchCode.js:**

```
Template.searchCode.helpers({
    result: function () {
        return Codes.findOne();
    }
});
```

**router.js:**

```
FlowRouter.route('/name/:query', {
    subscriptions: function (params, queryParams) {
        this.register('name', Meteor.subscribe('Name', params.query));
    },
    action: function () {
        BlazeLayout.render('mainLayout', {
            main: 'searchName'
        });
    },
    name: 'searchName'
});
FlowRouter.route('/code/:query', {
    subscriptions: function (params, queryParams) {
        this.register('code', Meteor.subscribe('Code', params.query));
    },
    action: function () {
        BlazeLayout.render('mainLayout', {
            main: 'searchCode'
        });
    },
    name: 'searchCode'
});
```

**layout.html:**

```
<template name="layout">
    <div class="Layout">
        {{> Template.dynamic template=main}}
    </div>
</template>
```

**server/publications.js:**

```
Meteor.publish('Names', function () {
    return Names.find();
});
Meteor.publish('Name', function (_id) {
    return Names.find({
        _id: _id
    });
});
Meteor.publish('Codes', function () {
    return Codes.find();
});
Meteor.publish('Code', function (_id) {
    return Codes.find({
        _id: _id
    });
});
```

**lib/collections.js:**

```
Names = new Mongo.Collection('names');
Codes= new Mongo.Collection('codes');
```

Comment: Sorry, i´m newbie in Meteor and i only used iron:router :( I´m going to take a look at flow-router to see if i understand this. Thanks

Comment: Let me explain. We create two different collections (Names and Codes) and defined the way how to get access to them in server/publications.js; And we have 2 templates. Router is helping to subscribe to publications and render the layout. On app:3000/name/Stive our router will take `Stive` as a query and get Names.find({ _id: 'Stive' }); Router will help render the searchName template, and result: function () { return Names.findOne();} will return our old query - Names.find({ _id: 'Stive' });

Comment: If we change the path of our application, we will do the same thing to other collection and get other result.